# Checkbox Validations

Tags: javascript, validation

I cant simply get my head around javascript validations. I've seen tutorials and its just not getting to me. Someone please give me a SIMPLE step by step guide on how I can add validations to checkboxes. So say this is my form:

```
<form name="form1" method = "post">

<input name="Conservatives" type="checkbox" value="Conservatives" /> Conservative

<input name="Liberal Democrats" type="checkbox" value="Liberal Democrats" /> Liberal Democrats

<input name="Labour" type="checkbox" value="Labour" /> Labour


</form>
```

i want the user to select at least 2 checkboxes. the validation should be done from the client side of things which i will then take the values using php to send to the database?
any help guys?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to validate that, based on your comment, at least two of these checkboxes are checked?  I would give them all the same name:

```
<input name="partyAffiliation" type="checkbox" value="Conservatives" /> Conservative
<input name="partyAffiliation" type="checkbox" value="Liberal Democrats" /> Liberal Democrats
<input name="partyAffiliation" type="checkbox" value="Labour" /> Labour
```

Then loop them and see how many are checked.  `document.getElementsByName` will give you the checkboxes, each of which will have a `checked` property.

```
var allCbs = document.getElementsByName("partyAffiliation");
var numChecked = 0;
for(var i = 0, max = allCbs.length; i < max; i++)
    if (allCbs[i].checked)
        numChecked++;

if (numChecked < 2)
   alert("Select at least two parties!");
```

---

I don't know the details of your project, but I'll just mention that jQuery will make the above code quite simple, if using this library is something you're not opposed to:

```
var numChecked = $("input[name='partyAffiliation']:checked").length;

if (numChecked < 2)
   alert("Select at least two parties!");
```

---

**EDIT**

In response to a comment below, don't worry about having multiple inputs with the same name.  Your server-side code should receive a comma delimited list of all (selected) values associated with that name.  So if you check all three checkboxes, you'd see something like the below.

[image]

Comment: How would you then differentiate the checkboxes on the server side, if they have the same name?

Comment: i want the user to select at least 2 checkboxes. the validation should be done from the client side of things which i will then take the values using php to send to the database?

Comment: @MohemaBurhan - ok, then instead of an anyChecked, you'd keep a running total of how many are checked, and compare to two.

Comment: @Kolink - no - it'll send all selected values for that name.  See my edit

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you actually want radio buttons, not checkboxes.

If that is the case, use this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label><input type="radio" name="vote" value="Conserv" /> Conservative</label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="vote" value="LibDem" /> Liberal Democrats</label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="vote" value="Labour" /> Labour</label><br />
</form>
```

Then, in whatever server-side code you have, the `vote` POST variable will have either `"Conserv"`, `"LibDem"` or `"Labour"` depending on user choice.

Comment: i want the user to select at least 2 checkboxes. the validation should be done from the client side of things which i will then take the values using php to send to the database?