# Tesing if at least two checkboxes are checked then insert the values into data base

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, wampserver

I am using html,php, javascript,mysql and wampserver.

I have 3 checkboxes, the user should maximum check two , then I insert the two choices into my database.

I have declared 3 checkboxes with different name attribute  (different => because I have declared 3 variables in my php code)

but then when I want to insert the validation using javascript (to validate that just maximum 2 checkboxs are checked)
I found that I should declare the 3 checkboxes with the same attribute name

My question is :

To insert the user choises into my database I should declare 3 variables so 3 different name attribute,

and to validate checkboxes  :2 at least are checked I have to use the same name attribue

Is there another solution that I dont know?

**HTML code:**

```
<input type="checkbox"  value="workshop1Day1" id="workshop" name="workshop1Day1" />Workshop I
<input type="checkbox" value="workshop2Day1"  name="workshop2Day1" />Workshop II

<input type="checkbox" value="workshop3Day1"  name="workshop3Day1" />Workshop III
```

**php code**

```
 $workshop1Day1 = $_POST["workshop1Day1"];
 $workshop2Day1 = $_POST["workshop2Day1"];
 $workshop3Day1 = $_POST["workshop3Day1"];

 $requete = "INSERT INTO Participant (workshop1Day1,workshop2Day1,workshop3Day1)
                  VALUES ('$workshop1Day1', '$workshop2Day1', '$workshop3Day1')";
```

**The java script that I found (use the same value for the name attribute**

[Checkbox Validations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386901/checkbox-validations?rq=1)

thank you

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If I understand well you can just check it by isset() if workshop2Day1 exists it means that this checkbox was checked.

Answer (score 3):

This might be helpful for you:

```
<script>
function checkifclicked()
{

    //alert($('input[name=cb]').val());
    var checkboxs=document.getElementsByName("cb");
    var okay=false;
    var count = 0;
    for(var i=0,l=checkboxs.length;i<l;i++)
    {
        if(checkboxs[i].checked)
        {

        count++;
        }
    }
    if(count > 1){
     okay=true;    
    }
    if(!okay){

        alert("Please check at least two checkbox");
        return false;
    }

}
</script>


<form name="send_email" id="send_email" action="send_email.php" onSubmit="return checkifclicked()" method="post">

<div id="checkbox">    
<input type="checkbox" id="1" name="cb"/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="cb"/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="3" name="cb"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</div>


</form>
```

[Codepad Demo>>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NONeuI)

Comment: You used the same name attribute for the 3 checkboxes! So please can you tell me how you will insert the two choices into the database?

Comment: but to recuperate a variable in php code we use it's name eg: <input name="lastname" type="text" /> in php $lastname= $_POST['lastname'];